# Cannot change the PATH in a script task in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-pipelines

As part of an Azure Pipelines build I need to install some tool and add it to the `PATH` for subsequent use (by an Ant task), using a script task (on a Windows host). After (a lot) of research I found what should solve my problem: namely the [`##vso[task.prependpath]` logging command](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md). But I cannot make it work on my project. Something like the following does nothing, the `PATH` is left unchanged:

```yaml
steps:
- script: |
    ECHO ##vso[task.prependpath]%AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY%\.tmp\node_modules\.bin
    IF NOT EXIST .tmp MKDIR .tmp
    IF NOT EXIST .tmp\node_modules\.bin\sfdx (
      PUSHD .tmp
      npm install sfdx-cli
      POPD
    )
  displayName: Install SFDX CLI
```

What am I doing wrong?

NB: [the complete configuration is on GitHub](https://github.com/mcartoixa/ant-sfdx/blob/b9cc08a047f6677e81791b8d9e3245f4b40bea5e/azure-pipelines.yml).

Answer (score 3):

The official documentation about how to set variables within a script:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script

Batch

```
@echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes
@echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic
```

PowerShell

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with
            garlic"
```

Shell

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=sauce]crushed tomatoes"
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=secret.Sauce;issecret=true]crushed tomatoes with garlic"
```

Answer (score 2):

Tested the command `ECHO ##vso[task.prependpath]%AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY%\.tmp\node_modules\.bin` at my side, it works. `D:\avsts140\_work\2\.tmp\node_modules\.bin;` is added to path successfully.

Please make sure that you are checking if the path is changed in the next build task as the updated environment variable only be reflected in subsequent tasks.

Comment: As you may see in the complete script, I have a subsequent dedicated task that echoes all the environment variables (command SET, line 52). My path does not appear to have been changed. https://dev.azure.com/mcartoixa/ant-sfdx/_build/results?buildId=17&view=logs

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `bash` on Windows host, once path is prepended, it will be accessible only from separate task.

For example:
You prepend path in one script and access in another.

```
steps:         
- script: |
    echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$(PROGRAM)/bin"  #prepend path

- script: |
    program.exe    #access program here
```